# Rails 4.1 & RSpec 3: How can I show the HTTP requests/responses of a particular example?

Tags: http, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

The title says it all, really. I want to see the HTTP requests my tests send, to make sure I'm testing the right thing.

Comment: What type(s) of RSpec specs do you mean? feature specs or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **charles proxy** to see the http traffic